# MS SQL - syncronising "a view" to another MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let me open by saying that I am no MSSQL expert. I'm a linux admin, so please forgive me if I should know this.

I've been asked to syncronise a view or a table from one MSSQL database to another. I've been told it's a bit like MySQL replication, except that instead of the whole database, it's just one table. Or in the case of MSSQL, the results of a particular search, or whatever, basically a subset of the data in the main database.

I understand the concept, I just do not know the MS way of doing things. Any hints and tips to point me in the right direction would be great. Starting with maybe the correct terminology!

Thanks for helping out a newbie!

Comment: Did you try - cough - doing something arcane such as reading the documentation? Keyword "Replication". In SQL Server since 7.0 and - fully documented. Newbie or not, on a forum for administrators in a  professional capacity you should not sound like someone too lazy to even look at the documentation. And it is impossible to not stumble over it when going through the TOC (Table of Contents) of books online.

Comment: Thanks Tom - your answer is most "helpful" - I did ask to be pointed in the right direction. I don't want to have to research MSSQL only to find I can't replicate only small parts of it - But thanks. I'm sorry that I seemed like I was too lazy to search, I have been - I have other people watching this question, and your response is the proof I need to show why SAs do not like doing other peoples research - but that's another story...

Comment: Great, thn look up replication. It is QUITE powerfull, with "table" but also "filter based" - i.e. you can use it to replicate parts of a table out to a specific other server, such as a sales system where every laptop of an agent only has HIS relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559.aspx - This is a way of publishing a subset of data from a database to another